# How can we resize a graph?

Tags: support, editing, images, formatting

Is it possible to resize a graph in a post?
For example, I wanted to resize this one, because the original size looks much better.
[image]

Comment: I am not really sure why this question is tagged ([meta-tag:bug]).

Answer (score 6):

You can also use standard image html, of the form `<img src="image/source.png" width="image_width" height="image_height">`, except with the quoted constants filled in appropriately.

For example, I've included a manually resized version of your graph.

[image]

`<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrHvg.png" width="450" height="300">`

Comment: I have edited your answer to show the actual code used for the example in your post. (Since users who are relatively new might not know how to display source of the code.) I hope the edit is ok - feel free to revert it if you prefer the original version.

Comment: Note that it's also possible to use `width` only or `height` only to preserve the aspect ratio.